# Is my computation correct? distribution of an inverse function

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

Let $ X \sim U[-1,2]$ and let Y:

$$
 Y=\begin{cases} 
   \frac{1}{X^2} && X \ne 0 \\
   0 && X=0
  \end{cases}
$$

Find the distribution of  Y.

What I did was:

$F_Y(t)=P(Y\leq t)=P(\frac{1}{X^2}\leq t)$

Obviously, if $t<0$ then $F_Y(t)=0$

Since $X^2$ is non negative, $P(\frac{1}{X^2}\leq t)=P(X^2\geq \frac{1}{t})=1-P(X^2 \leq \frac{1}{t})=1-P(-\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}\leq X \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{t}})$

Now I wonder. The simplest thing I can do here is to simply integrate over the region:

$=1-\int_{-\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}}^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}}\frac{1}{3}dx=1-\frac{1}{3}(\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}})=1-\frac{2}{3\sqrt{t}}$

Is that correct?

Is there a reasonable way to do that without integration? I mean by using the fact that$P(-\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}\leq X \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}) = F_X(\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}) - F_X(-\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}})$ but then I'll have to consider every case for $\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}$ and $-\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}$ which is pretty much a mess, no?

Thanks.

Comment: Your computation is correct for $t$ such that your calculated expression for $\mathbb{P}\left(\frac{1}{X^2} \leq t\right)$ is non-negative. However, for certain values of $t$, this expression becomes negative, so you should separately account for these values of $t$.

Comment: @MinusOne-Twelfth could you please give more details?

Comment: When you did $\int_{-1/\sqrt{t}}^{1/\sqrt{t}}\frac{1}{3}\, dx$, you were implicitly assuming that the interval $\left[-1/\sqrt{t}, 1/\sqrt{t}\right]$ is contained in the interval $[-1,2]$. (This is because $\mathbb{P}(a \leq X \leq b) = \int_a^b \frac{1}{3}\, dx$ only if $[a,b] \subseteq [-1,2]$.) However, this assumption does not hold if $t$ is less than a certain positive value.

Comment: @MinusOne-Twelfth so I should separate to the following cases? $-\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}} < -1$ or $\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}} >2$?

Comment: For example, if you substitute $t = 0.01$ into your formula, you should find you get a negative value, which cannot be a probability.

Comment: You could do that, but you could also note that since $X$ is between $-1$ and $2$ with probability $1$, we have $X^2\leq 4$ with probability $1$. And remember you were calculating $\mathbb{P}\left(X^2 \leq 1/t\right)$. So for values of $t$ such that $1/t > 4$, what can you say about this probability?

Comment: @MinusOne-Twelfth not sure I am following, but I got a similar result

Comment: OK, best then to take cases as you suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINTS: Your calculation of $\mathbb{P}\left(-1/\sqrt{t}\leq X \leq 1/\sqrt{t}\right)$ has assumed that $-1/\sqrt{t}\geq -1$ and $1/\sqrt{t}\leq 2$. It is correct if these inequalities hold, but you should separately consider what happens if one or more of them do not hold.

Basically when computing something like $\mathbb{P}(a \leq X\leq b)$, if $a < -1$ or $b > 2$, you will want to truncate these bounds to the bounds of the interval that $X$ is uniform on ($-1$ and $2$). For example, if $a < -1$, then $\mathbb{P}(a \leq X \leq 1)$ would become $\mathbb{P}(-1\leq X \leq 1)$. Once you have $[a',b']\subseteq [-1,2]$, you will be able to use $\mathbb{P}(a'\leq X \leq b') =(b'-a')/3$.